# CollectRates() in getAllItems() is empty

Tags: magento2.4

I'm using Magento 2.4.6.

When I try to access `$request->getAllItems()` it returns an empty array.

Also, I'm trying with Quote and the same result.

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request) // NOSONAR
    {

        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->_logger->info('COLLECT RATES 0 '. json_encode($request->toArray()));
        $this->_logger->info('COLLECT RATES 1 '. json_encode($this->_quote->getAllVisibleItems()));
        $this->_logger->info('COLLECT RATES 2 '. json_encode($this->_quote->getAllItems()));
        $this->_logger->info('COLLECT RATES 3 '. json_encode($this->_quote->getData()));
        $this->_logger->info('COLLECT RATES 4 '. json_encode($this->_quote->getCustomer()));
```

output:

```
[2023-11-16T13:20:20.882524+00:00] main.INFO: COLLECT RATES 0 {"all_items":[{},{}],....} [] []
[2023-11-16T13:20:20.883382+00:00] main.INFO: COLLECT RATES 1 [] [] []
[2023-11-16T13:20:20.883596+00:00] main.INFO: COLLECT RATES 2 [] [] []
[2023-11-16T13:20:20.883680+00:00] main.INFO: COLLECT RATES 3 [] [] []
[2023-11-16T13:20:20.884622+00:00] main.INFO: COLLECT RATES 4 {} [] []
```

What I'm missing?

thanks

Comment: is it a custom shipping method ?

Comment: @Pawan yup. I do it by magento generator module (https://mage2gen.com/)

Comment: How you are getting the quote item ? ```$this->_quote```

Comment: @VyacheslavShmal importing use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote, then Injection in constructor and using in collectRates()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with json_encode. Use json_encode on item level.

```
    foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item){
            $this->_logger->info('COLLECT RATES 2 '. json_encode($item->getData()));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this quote class `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote` is not populated with the `customer data`, that is why you are not getting the products. Try `$request->getAllItems()`  to get the products, otherwise try getting the quote from customer session.

```
    protected $checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession    
    ){
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function getQuotes()
    {
         return $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();       
    }
```

Comment: Still empty :/

`$this->_logger->info('COLLECT RATES 1 '. json_encode($request->toArray()));
$this->_logger->info('COLLECT RATES 2 '. json_encode($this->checkoutSession->getQuote()));
$this->_logger->info('COLLECT RATES 3 '. json_encode($this->getQuotes())); `

Comment: what about ```$request->getAllItems()``` ?

Comment: Empty too. With $request->toArray(), show me the "all_items" and is empty. If I try as $request->getAllItems() also are empty :/

Comment: It is weird because if I use `$this->checkoutSession->getQuoteId()` it return the correct ID.

Comment: Try loading the quote by id then, to see if it loads. ```\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository``` ```$this->quoteRepository->get($quoteId);```